# Vert.x - Not able to decode json to list of objects

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm using the latest version of Vert.x (4.3.2) and I wrote and handler for a route that serves a POST method.

Below my code to convert the JSON  body of that method to a List of objects:

```
Class<List<CartLineItem>> cls = (Class<List<CartLineItem>>)(Object)List.class;
List<CartLineItem> itemsToAdd = rc.body().asPojo(cls);
```

Unforntunately whenever I try to iterate over `itemsToAdd` I get the exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.acme.CartLineItem`.

How can I fix this issue without using any other library except Vert.x (I mean .. using Jackson I would provide a TypeReference<List> object)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vert.x 3 there was method that you could use:

`Json.decodeValue(result.bodyAsString(), new TypeReference<List<ConditionDTO>>() {});`

Since in Vert.x 4 this was removed you will need to use specific class DatabindCodec:
`io.vertx.core.json.jackson.DatabindCodec.fromString(result.bodyAsString(), new TypeReference<List<SimpleDTO>>() {})`

If you don't want to use external libraries there is an option to iterate over an jsonArray that you have in body assuming body is something like this:

```js
[{"name":"Lazar", "age":27},{"name":"Nikola", "age":33}]
```

```java
List<SimpleDTO> list = routingContext.body().asJsonArray()
    .stream()
    .map(json -> Json.decodeValue(json.toString(), SimpleDTO.class))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi @Pendula, thank you, I followed your latest advice. I only removed the `getBodyAsJsonArray` method since it's deprecated and used `routingContext.body().asJsonArray()` instead.

Comment: You are welcome, updated the answer so it does not contain deprecated method.